# Compact metric spaces without continuous surjective functions between them.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

There exist two compact metric spaces such that doesn't exist a continuous and surjective function between them? That is, two compact metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that for every surjective functions $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to X$, $f$ and $g$ aren't continuous.

Comment: In the title and first sentence you ask for an example where there is no continuous function but your last sentence then seems to suggest you want an example where there is no discontinuous function. Which one of these is correct?

Comment: It looks like you are contradicting yourself. Are you asking about "no continuous functions" or "any function is continuous"?

Comment: No continuous functions

Comment: Constant functions are always continuous.

Comment: I asked wrong. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ and $Y=[0,1]$, both with the usual metric inherited from $\Bbb R$; both are compact metric spaces. There is no surjection at all from $X$ to $Y$, since $X$ is countable and $Y$ is uncountable, and there is no continuous surjection from $Y$ to $X$, since $Y$ is connected, and $X$ is not. (Recall that continuous functions preserve connectedness.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @oioa: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Let $X, Y$ be non-empty, then there exists a constant function from $X$ to $Y$ and one in the reverse direction. Both are continuous, since constant functions are continuous.

If one of them is empty, the functions between $X$ and $Y$ are all continuous (vacuously).

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer

Comment: And with the hypothesis of being surjective there exists some example?

Comment: @oioa No, consider the singleton spaces, then the only function is a constant and surjective function.